# VSCODE LARAVEL XDEBUG PHP DEBUG extension - not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a laravel app using vscode. It seems that xdebug *is* connecting but I'm having no luck so far with the breakpoints. I have set a few but it is not stopping as intended.

Here is my config and logs.

I start listening in vscode with F5, and then I run php artisan serve on the terminal.

php.ini ->

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_port=9091
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log=C:\xampp\xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9091,
            "log": true
        }
    ]
}
```

C:\xampp\xdebug.log

```
[241672] Log opened at 2020-02-28 20:02:30
[241672] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9091.
[241672] I: Connected to client. :-)
[241672] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/artisan" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.13" protocol_version="1.0" appid="241672" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.9.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[241672] <- breakpoint_list -i 1
[241672] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

[241672] <- breakpoint_set -i 2 -t line -f file:///c:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php -n 48
[241672] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="2" id="1106000001"></response>

[241672] <- breakpoint_list -i 3
[241672] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="3"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php" lineno="48" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="1106000001"></breakpoint></response>

[241672] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t line -f file:///c:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/API/Driver/UserAPIController.php -n 40
[241672] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="1106000002"></response>

[241672] <- breakpoint_list -i 5
[241672] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="5"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/API/Driver/UserAPIController.php" lineno="40" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="1106000002"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php" lineno="48" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="1106000001"></breakpoint></response>

[241672] <- breakpoint_list -i 6
[241672] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="6"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/API/Driver/UserAPIController.php" lineno="40" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="1106000002"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php" lineno="48" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="1106000001"></breakpoint></response>

[241672] <- run -i 7
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at using this VSCode extension? `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug` It provides documentation to setup with xdebug.

Comment: Do the files in the <init packet and breakpoint_set commands match with files on disk?

Comment: fileuri="file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/artisan" this is the only URI that is wrong,  i am running "php artisan serve" as usual

Comment: How is the URL wrong? That's the one that Xdebug actually sees as PHP code being run. Is it possible that "php artisan serve" ends up calling that script?

Comment: yes you are right!! i was wrong that uri was fine, there is a artisan file without extension and a server.php at root level in any laravel project, but for some reason is not stopping on breakpoints.  if i launch with php -S works fine, and the logs shows file:///C:/Development/Menuu/menuu_backend_dev/server.php intead of /artisan, i will use php -S or just use apache when i need to debug, i just start with laravel and php a few weeks ago and this was driving me crazy :P thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Place your breakpoints on lines that have code.

If you place your breakpoints on BLANK LINES it will not work, it will just skip them.